# How do I write to the device Console log from the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, high-sierra, console, macos

How do I write to the log for my "Device" in the Console app from the command line. I've [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819247/656912)

```
syslog -s -k Facility com.apple.console \
             Level Alert \
             Sender SomeSender \
             Message "some message"
```

and

```
syslog -s -l error "message to send"
```

but don't see anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has a new logging system so the old tail and syslog commands are deprecated. To start down the new unified log path, open two windows the first will just stream the logs (and they will fly by quickly normally)

```
log stream
```

Then to emit a log:

```
logger -p user.error "my new alert"
```

More good links:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging
- https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/10/inside-the-macos-log-logd-and-the-files-that-it-manages/
- http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/logs-logging-logger-oh/

Comment: I don't see that in the Console app.

Comment: @orome Likely you have filters or user.error doesn't show in Console. Search for "alert" in the search window or logger as the process for Console and you should see the message. You can use `date && logger -p user.error "my new alert"` so you know exactly what time to scroll to in Console. I don't have to do anything to see these on my system.

Comment: It shows now. No way to tag with a yellow or a red dot (so it appears when filtering "Errors and Faults")? I'd have thought `.error` would do that.